# Pulling image from local docker registry: download completed, but image not found

Tags: docker, docker-registry

has anyone seen that? I'm running a local registry, image uploaded from other machine, can be accessed on yet another machine but not locally where the registry is installed.

Docker version 1.5.0, build a8a31ef/1.5.0

2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64

```
[root@hhh radek]# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
fb50aaacd282        registry:2.0        "registry cmd/regist   15 minutes ago      Up 15 minutes       0.0.0.0:8180->5000/tcp   high_torvalds       

[root@hhh radek]# docker pull hhh:8180/name/oracle:latest
...
75550c09ec78: Pulling fs layer 
3912e3898de8: Pulling fs layer 
7d513a058ccf: Layer already being pulled by another client. Waiting. 
7d513a058ccf: Download complete 
FATA[0000] Error: image name/oracle:latest not found
```

Comment: This looks very similar to an unreported checksum failure seen here: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/10256 . Did you perhaps intervene manually in some way in the registry directories? Can you see any checksum failures in the docker daemon or registry logs?

Comment: I think docker 1.5 is a bit dodgy with registry 2.0; try updating.

Comment: I can't dig into the logs now, but downgrading the registry to 0.9.1 fixes the issue.